# Transforming matrix element for Coulomb interaction from position to momentum space

Tags: homework-and-exercises, notation, coulombs-law

I'm stuck with the Dirac notation in this calculation. I have the Coulomb interaction given by the matrix $$\langle x|V|x' \rangle = V(|x-x'|) = \frac{1}{|x-x'|}$$

and I want to go to the momentum representation, i.e. calculate $\langle k|V|k' \rangle$. I wrote

$$\langle k|V|k' \rangle= \iint d^3x d^3x' \langle k | x \rangle \langle x | V | x' \rangle \langle x'|k' \rangle$$

where I know that $\langle k | x \rangle = e^{-ik\cdot x}$, but this doesn't get me anywhere. I don't know how to simplify the double integral. I'm supposed to get $\langle k|V|k' \rangle = 4\pi\delta(k-k')/k^2$, but I can't proceed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take the equation that defines the [Green's function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Green%27s_function) for the 3-dimensional negative Laplace operator:$$-\nabla^2 G(\mathbf{x}, \mathbf{x}') = \delta(\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{x}'),$$ Fourier transform both sides with respect to both $\mathbf{x}$ and $\mathbf{x}'$ to get:
$$\mathbf{k}^2 G(\mathbf{k}, \mathbf{k}') = \delta(\mathbf{k}-\mathbf{k}'),$$ and note that in this case $$G(\mathbf{x},\mathbf{x}') = \frac{1}{4\pi|\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{x}'|}.$$ You also need to note that $\mathbf{x}$ and $\mathbf{x}'$ Fourier transform with opposite senses, as implied by your second equation.

Comment: Where can I read about the connection between these matrix elements and Green's functions?

Comment: It's the definition of $V$ from classical electromagnetism. The potential of a point charge satisfies: $$-\nabla^2 \Phi = \frac{q}{\epsilon_0} \delta(\vec{x}-\vec{x}')$$ for a charge at $\vec{x}'$, making it proportional to the Green's function. See any intermediate or higher book on E&M: [Griffiths](https://www.amazon.com/Introduction-Electrodynamics-4th-David-Griffiths/dp/8120347765/), [Pollack & Stump](https://www.amazon.com/Electromagnetism-Gerald-L-Pollack/dp/0805385673/), [Jackson](https://www.amazon.com/Classical-Electrodynamics-Third-David-Jackson/dp/047130932X/), etc.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is a very heavy calculation that I once struggled through myself...
If you want to arrive at the desired result from your definitions and notations above, you must do the following:
First normalize your plane-waves properly... Note the translation-invariance of the Coulomb-potential in position space and make use of it by shifting the intregrand in your expression. Performing one integral over position-space will give you the desired Kronecker-delta. After that, you are left with one three-dimensional integral, and all you have to do is follow the lines of [this calculation](https://blog.cupcakephysics.com/electromagnetism/math%20methods/2014/10/04/the-fourier-transform-of-the-coulomb-potential.html) (i.e. disturbing the integrand a little bit to perform the integral to arrive at the final result...)